# ошибка вывода var_dump response

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $nomer = Yii::$app->user->identity->iin_bin;
    var_dump($nomer);

    $searchModel = new ResolutionsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Когда контроллер напрямую через вардамп вывожу что-то снизу выходит ошибка `response` и т.д. На картинке видно.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вызвана тем, что как только PHP получает первый вывод в ответ (например, `echo, print или var_dump`), автоматически добавляются ***хедеры*** в серверный ответ. Но поскольку после вывода var_dump у вас программа не прекращает свою работу, дальше по коду Yii2 вызывает еще раз посыл в ответ новых ***хедеров***. Это и вызывает ошибку. Иными словами PHP ругается: "Вы пытаетесь послать в ответ хедеры, но ведь я уже это сделал ранее".

**Как решение** (если вам нужно посмотреть содержимое переменной), можете остановить выполнение скрипта с помощью `die()`, либо `exit()`, либо `Yii::$app->end()`.

**P.S.** Кстати, для "красивого" дебага переменных в Yii2 есть класс-хелпер [VarDumper](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper)

**P.P.S** А еще лучше настроить XDebug. Примеры настройки [тут](https://habr.com/post/250323/) и [тут](https://habr.com/post/328094/)

Comment: Как вариант еще можно использовать Yii::debug($var, 'qwe'); и смотреть в панели дебагера в логах, фильтруя по категории qwe.